# Redux consumer not passing updated props to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

`redux@6.0.0`

I am working to add redux to a server-side rendered React app. The architecture for the app is a black box, but I have successfully [set up redux following this example from the docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering).

I can read data from the redux store and render it on the screen. I can dispatch actions that update the store. Those changes trickle down to the `Context.Consumer` (and can be verified in React DevTools), but stop there. Despite the change, the value is never passed to the component after the initial mount.

[I read here that "99.9% of the time" this is due to mutating state](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2190#issuecomment-271109542). So I added another store with a boilerplate value and action to update it:

```js
const ACTIONS = {
    SET_RANDOM_TEST_VALUE: 'SET_RANDOM_TEST_VALUE',
}

const initialState = {
    testValue: 'intial test value', // I now see this typo, but the screenshots are final ‍♂️
}

export const setRandomTestValue = () => ({
    type: ACTIONS.SET_RANDOM_TEST_VALUE,
})

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.SET_RANDOM_TEST_VALUE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                testValue: String(Math.random()).slice(-5),
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

My test reducer is added to the `rootReducer`:

```js
import { reducer as testReducer } from './TestStore.redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // ...
    __test__: testReducer,
})
```

Then the values are mapped to the component:

```js
/* Import assets */

const Test = props => {
    console.count('Render count')
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.setRandomTestValue}>Update value</button>
            <code>{props.testValue}</code>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(
    state => ({ testValue: state.__test__.testValue }),
    { setRandomTestValue }
)(Test)
```

With this set up, everything seems to work. The console logs `Render count: 1`, and the component displays `initial test value` -- all as expected:

[image: A screenshot of the Test component displaying correctly on initial render]

When you click the button, the action fires and the store is updated (as shown here in redux logger):

[image: A screenshot of the action logged in the console by redux logger]

However, the component isn't called again and the content doesn't change:

[image: A screenshot of the action logged in console but no change to the component]

Tracking it down in React DevTools, you can see that the `Context.Consumer` does indeed have the updated value (the random string of numbers):

[image: A screenshot of the Context.Consumer component in React DevTools with the updated value]

^^^ Different value because screenshots are hard.

So the value makes it to the Consumer, but that's as far as it gets. When you check the props of the `Test` component, it still has the initial value:

[image: A screenshot of the Test component in React DevTools with stale props.]

`:sad-trombone:`

### tl;dr

Somewhere in this project there is a breakdown between the redux store consumer and the component who is expecting updated props. The component can read the initial value from the store, but is unable to receive updates.

Due to the complexity of this project, I'm not looking for an answer *per se*. I just need to know what direction to look. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this still happen if you update to `react-redux@^7.1.1`?  Also, is there any kind of multi-folder workspace setup with this project (Lerna, `npm link`, etc)?

Comment: @markerikson I can't update to past `6.0.0` because our current state management library is tied to the old old Context API. No multi-folders.

Comment: can't reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-rain-c5f66

Comment: If you're on 6.0, then you're already using the new context API.  Do you mean you're on v5.x instead?  And out of curiosity, what do you mean "current state management library"?

Comment: *Pre-hook context. We're on `react@16.6.3` and `react-redux@6.0.0`. The current state management library is `fluxible@1.4.0`.

Comment: Uh... I'm confused.  Are you hooking Fluxible into React-Redux somehow?  Or are you using both Redux and Fluxible at the same time?

Comment: can you post the code where you setup `<Provider />` and creating the store?

Comment: @markerikson The app currently uses Fluxible, but we want to switch to Redux. The current plan is to run both and slowly migrate from the former to the latter.

Comment: @DanielLizik The setup is exactly the same as this example from the docs: https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering

Comment: So I'm still confused on why you say you're limited to React-Redux v6.  If you're just now adding Redux, you should be able to use v7, even if something Fluxible-related still relies on using the old context API internally.

Comment: @markerikson The peer dependency for `redux@7.1.0` is `react@^16.8.3`. We're still on `16.6.3`. https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v7.1.0/package.json#L39

Comment: You should also be able to upgrade React from 16.6 to 16.8.3 with no problems.  It's a minor release, and there are no backwards compatibility problems.  (Note that 16.9 _does_ start warning about the deprecated lifecycle methods like `componentWillMount`, but the code runs fine.)